# MS Project Elapsed Day Task Ends on Weekend

Tags: ms-project

I am currently working on a project where a task requires a block of time to achieve a total amount of exposure, so I've been using the elapsed days duration function. In this case, the task requires 17 days of exposure, but the end lands on a Saturday.

The problem is that the next task must start immediately after the end of the exposure time, but it has to start on a weekday. Is there a way to connect the tasks so the the previous one pushes up if required or forbid ending on weekends?

Sorry if this is obvious, I'm really new to MS Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Change Working Time method described by Richard to alter the working time of two different resources; those that can work weekends and those that cannot. So you make those changes on the Resource calendars, not the Project calendar.

Then for the task that must start on the following weekday apply a resource that cannot work weekends- it will automatically schedule to the next non-weekend slot. However for those tasks that are allowed to spill over into a weekend, apply resources where weekends are allowed as working time.

If you want the combination, where a task must start on a weekday but may overspill into a weekend, then there is currently no way to handle that automatically within MS-Project. You will need to force the scheduling to conform to your requirements by manually setting start dates or adding lag to the predecessor dependencies.

Comment: Okay that last line answered my question. I do have a calendar with weekends set as non working days and resources who all are set to not work weekends, but the elapsed day task spills into the weekend. Like you said it auto schedules it the next monday, which can't happen because the next task needs to start immediately. Thank you for your help! Guess I'll have to work it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Hi this will be down to the calendar you have set up.

I'm not sure what version of MSP you are using but if you go to Project > Change Working time you can control what type of calendar you use and set weekends as non working time.

Just another quick tip if your linking tasks. If you want tasks to start one after another make sure they are set to "Auto Schedule"